# Display the chosen selected CF7 from admin on Woocommerce single products

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, contact-form-7

For a custom WooCommerce theme I'm trying to achieve the following:

1. **Backend**

   - User can select if product can have a product enquiry form
   - User can select a CF7 form from within a single product from a dropdown.
2. **Frontend**

   - Single product page displays standard product information but if the "product enquiry form" is checked then the single product page displays a button that says "Product Enquiry"
   - When that button is clicked a CF7 form is displayed that contains product attributes (sizes,colors,etc)

Example of what I'm trying to achieve.
http://www.blumeta.nl/tuininrichting/houtopslag/cortenstaal-houtopslag-500-x-hoogte-x-380mm

I really don't know how to approach this. Can anybody help me out how i can achieve this.

All help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code below will display in:

**1) Backend** single product settings under "Advanced tab" a select field with your different CF7 forms

[image]

You will have to set in the first function your CF7 forms shortcodes:

```
// Select field options: HERE set the CF7 shortcodes and labels in the array
function product_cf7_form_options() {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    return array(
        ''                          => __('Choose a form to enable it', $domain ), // Disabled choice
        '[contact-form-7 id="381"]' => __( 'First Form label name (or title)', $domain ),
        '[contact-form-7 id="382"]' => __( 'Second Form label name (or title)', $domain ),
    );
}

// Admin: Add custom field to product "advanced" setting tab
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_options_advanced', 'add_field_product_options_advanced', 20, 1 );
function add_field_product_options_advanced() {
    $domain = 'woocommerce';

    echo '<div class="option_group">';

    woocommerce_wp_select( array(
        'id'      => '_enquiry_form',
        'label'   => __( 'Display a form (CF7)', $domain ),
        'desc_tip' => true,
        'description' => __( 'This will automatically insert your slider into the single product page', $domain ),
        'options'  => product_cf7_form_options(), // Get the array of options
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Admin: Save custom field value from product "advanced" setting tab
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_custom_field', 20, 1 );
function save_product_custom_field( $post_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['_enquiry_form'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, '_enquiry_form', $_POST['_enquiry_form'] );

}
```

**2) Frontend** single product pages below add to cart button, the selected CF7 form

[image]

The code below will show up a button "Product Enquiry". If the customer click on the button it will disappear, displaying the selected Contact Form 7:

```
// Frontend: Custom button, display the selected product enquiry form
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_button', 'display_single_product_inquiry_form', 10 );
function display_single_product_inquiry_form(){
    global $product;

    // Get the selected form
    $enquiry_form = $product->get_meta('_enquiry_form');

    // Ouput button and hidden selected form hselected form
    if( ! empty($enquiry_form) ){
        echo '<div id="enquiry-form" style="padding-top:12px;">
        <p><a href="#" class="button">'.__("Product Enquiry", "woocommerce").'</a></p>
        <div style="display:none;">' . do_shortcode( "$enquiry_form" ) . '</div></div>';
    }

    // Jquery
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($){
        var a = '#enquiry-form';

        // On click hide button and show form.
        $(a+' a').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            $(a+' > div').show();
            $(this).hide();
        });
    })
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

All code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

Comment: WOW! Awesome! This was exactly was i was lookin for!